# How does C++ preprocessor work?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am reading the book "C++ Primer" 5th Edition and I read that the preprocessor is a program that runs before the C++ compiler and replaces the #include, #define and #ifdefs and others with the appropriate content and then transfer control over to the compiler.

But I came across a way in cl.exe (Microsoft Compiler) to view the preprocessor output saved directly to file. I did it, and when I opened the preprocessor output file I was surprised because I did not find what I expected!

They were totally big and contained what looked like obfuscated code!

**Please Explain what in reality does the Pre-Processor of C++ does.**

Comment: "I love C++ for being able to #define macros at the top of the code" - That's the first time I've ever heard somebody say that.

Comment: Don't blame the OP, I used to like writing std:: all over the place in C++, then it got annoying.

Comment: You might perhaps generate your Java code (with a preprocessor like [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) or something else).

Comment: I mean for the purpose of competitions alone, #defines simplify the typing a lot! 
:)

Comment: You can run a preprocessor on any text file. Probably not the one included in your compiler, but there are separate ones. Still seems like a pretty awful idea.

Comment: All good C++ compilers have options to show the preprocessor output... what are you missing?

Comment: What stops you from writing static methods in Java?

Comment: #defines on top of your code don't really mean alot. It's the #defines mixed with code that are the really useful ones.

Comment: A decent IDE simplifies typing a lot.

Comment: -1. I see no effort in researching the problem or that you have made any effort to try anything. A few seconds dancing a jig with Google came up with several possible solutions to your problem. I suggest you go dancing.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to pre-process Java just like you do C or C++. Just use something like this:

```
gcc -E myjava.java > myjava.preprocesses.java
```

Then you can use macro expansion, `#if` etc to your hearts content. Of course, it does have the drawback that there is a further tool needed for the compile.

Answer (score -2):

You can roll out a JNI lib that ties in with your native C/C++ code that has all your necessary macros.

Comment: It's as good and useful as the OP's, why the downvotes lol :D

Comment: -1. He's looking for a good way to apply a preprocessor to Java source files so he can use macros in Java. Using JNI won't solve that problem.