# What will be replaced with this statement?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

The statement is in a file:

```
#include "filename"
```

When will this file be replaced by its contents?

1. Before compilation
2. After compilation
3. During execution

Comment: Heh? Did you skip the chapter of preprocessing in your book?

Comment: The title of the question does not match the question itself.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253977/how-does-c-preprocessor-work

Comment: Compiling a C program is a multi-stage process. At an overview level, the process can be split into four separate stages: Preprocessing, compilation, assembly, and linking. Includes are resolved during the preprocessing phase.

Comment: I am studying it, but I was confused about it after going through the build process.

Comment: Before compilation.

Comment: Definitely not 2 or 3. The preprocessor could be part of the compilation process: it's not necessary that it occur "before compilation".

Comment: Which step in build process ?

Comment: Note that if the line `#include "filename"` is in a file called `filename`, then you won't get a successful compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing is performed before other phases of the compilation, but most modern compilers include the preprocessing phase as part of the compilation process.

The question is approximate:

- If you only have 3 choices, the expected answer is probably 1.
- If you can select *none of the above*, you are in trouble because you cannot determine if the question is stupid or subtile.
- If this is an interview question, here is your chance to tell the interviewer all you know about the compilation process, the parsing phases, etc.  The time limit will hit before the subject is exhausted.

Comment: ..unless NOTA is a hidden option ;)

Comment: @chqrlie  "If this is an interview question, here is your chance to tell the interviewer all you...think about him.":)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The OP needs to study the compilation process, it takes a long time to master every detail of that, most programmers never will, but understanding the basics is useful and demonstrated here.

Answer (score 1):

If to follow strictly this description from the C Standard (that does not use the word "compilation") (5.1.1 Translation environment, 5.1.1.1 Program structure)

> 1 A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of
>   the program is kept in units called source files, (or preprocessing
>   files) in this International Standard. **A source file together with
>   all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing
>   directive #include is known as a *preprocessing translation unit*.
>   After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a
>   *translation unit*.** Previously translated translation units may be
>   preserved individually or in libraries. The separate translation units
>   of a program communicate by (for example) calls to functions whose
>   identifiers have external linkage, manipulation of objects whose
>   identifiers have external linkage, or manipulation of data files.
>   **Translation units may be separately translated** and then later linked to 
>   produce an executable program.

So during preprocessing but before translation all #includes are substituted for source files.